# Objective-C, regular expression match repetition

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I found a problem in regular expression to match all group repetition.

This is a simple example:

```
NSString *string = @"A1BA2BA3BC";
NSString *pattern = @"(A[^AB]+B)+C";

NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:&error];
NSArray *array = [regex matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
```

Returning `array` have one element which contains two ranges, whole input string and last captured group `"A3B"`. First two groups, `"A1B"` and `"A2B"`, are not captured as I expected.

I've tried all from greedy to lazy matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A Quantifier Does not Spawn New Capture Groups**

Except in .NET, which has CaptureCollections, adding a quantifier to a capture group does not create more captures. The group number stays the same (in your case, Group 1), and the content returned is the last capture of the group.

**Reference**

[Everything about Regex Capture Groups](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html) (see *Generating New Capture Groups Automatically*)

**Iterating the Groups**

If you wanted to match all the substrings while still validating that they are in a valid string (composed of such groups and ending in C), you could use:

```
 A[^AB]+B(?=(?:A[^AB]+B)*C)
```

The whole string, of course, would be

```
^(?:A[^AB]+B)+C$
```

To iterate the substrings: something like

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"A[^AB]+B(?=(?:A[^AB]+B)*C)" options:0 error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:subject options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [subject length])];
NSUInteger matchCount = [matches count];
if (matchCount) {
    for (NSUInteger matchIdx = 0; matchIdx < matchCount; matchIdx++) {
        NSTextCheckingResult *match = [matches objectAtIndex:matchIdx];
        NSRange matchRange = [match range];
        NSString *result = [subject substringWithRange:matchRange];
    }
}
else {  // Nah... No matches.
     }
```

Comment: I see...So the only hope is, maybe, to capture all group, then loop through it and match first occurrence of repeating group.

Comment: If you wanted to match all the substrings while still validating that they are in a valid string (composed of such groups and ending in C), you could use `A[^AB]+B(?=(?:A[^AB]+B)*C)`

Comment: Added some code and discussion on that, but hanging up for the day now. :)

Comment: Sorry, your brain works faster than mine. I meant to match all string and then search again through it. Your answer is great, but I found a problem, always returns same subgroup. I couldn't find a solution for that.

Comment: Did you try the code I provided? The regex I gave you should find all the subgroups. See this [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/2). Going to bed, hope you figure it out. :)

Comment: Yes, I've tried it in my project. Thanks anyway to point me why my regex shouldn't work.

Comment: Maybe I haven't perfectly incorporated it in Objective-C, but you can see on the demo that all the substrings are matched. I just showed a `for` loop but inside it you could try to display each match?

Comment: It's OK, my mistake :)