# Regex java overwrites data in capturing group

Tags: java, regex

I have a small program for testing a regex that uses the match.group() function. It seems that this function only keeps the data for the last matched value for a group. Is there a way to get all the matches?

For example, I want to get all words of 3 or more letters, so I'd do :

```
(.*(\b\w{3,}\b).*)*
```

If my text is

```
I'm a newbie with regex
```

I get :

```
0: [0,23] I'm a newbie with regex
1: [0,23] I'm a newbie with regex
2: [18,23] regex
```

Edit: Here is my code but the output hereover is from http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

```
Pattern RegexCompile = Pattern.compile(args[1]);
Matcher m = RegexCompile.matcher(args[0]);
for(int i=1; i<=m.groupCount(); i++){
    System.out.println("Group: "+ i + "pattern:" + m.group(i));        
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Show us the actual code that "gets" the output you show. Without that, we are all just guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that feature is only specific for .NET.
In Java regex capture only last matching group.
For detailed answer check my similar question [Objective-C, regular expression match repetition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24631571/objective-c-regular-expression-match-repetition)

But, maybe you can write extra code to help regex to do the job. You can make iteration in which you can match last occurrence, remember it, then exclude that occurrence and repeat match, until no match is found.